# How to set major mode for a file in .dir-locals.el?

Tags: major-mode, directory-local-variables

I would like to set the major mode for a file as you would using file-local variables

```
Local Variables:
mode: text
End:
```

but in `.dir-locals.el` in order not to “pollute” the file in question.  Is this possible?

Comment: Is this purely for personal use, or something you want to be shareable? There are several ways you can tackle this in elisp, rather than resorting to directory-local variables.

Comment: @phils It would be nice to have a shareable solution, which is why I thought about dir-locals.  But practically, it is more or less personal.  (Unlikely to be shared with many people, and who knows if they use emacs and/or care).

Comment: Ok. I think utilising the `eval` pseudo-variable *is* the only way to handle it in a `.dir-locals.el` file. For custom elisp, you might just look at using `auto-mode-alist` to match the filename regexp (you can use `regexp-quote` to create patterns for verbatim string values, if necessary).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible to specify a string instead of a mode, but this only works for subdirectories.  So I'll use `nil` instead to match all modes, then the `eval` key to change the major mode conditionally:

```
((nil
  (eval
   (lambda ()
     (when (string= (file-name-nondirectory buffer-file-name)
                    "file-name.extension")
       (my-mode))))))
```

A downside of this approach is that the `eval` key is unsafe, so you'll need to confirm the variable permanently for this to have an effect.

Comment: Thanks, this works. 

Could someone explain the difference with the following form?

```
((nil . ((eval . (lambda ()
                    (when (string= (file-name-nondirectory (buffer-name)) "filename")
                      (my-mode)))))))
```

Comment: When I try to apply the mode using this I've got `(error "Lisp nesting exceeds ‘max-lisp-eval-depth’")` because it keeps trying to apply the mode in a loop.

Answer (score 5):

The following `.dir-locals.el` works just fine for me to set the major mode of all files in a directory to `shell-script-mode`:

```
((nil . ((mode . shell-script))))
```

The obvious downside is that you can't specify the major mode for only a given subset of files in the directory.

**Addendum:** Amusingly, it also has the side effect of setting the major mode of `.dir-locals.el` itself to `shell-script-mode`.

**Addendum 2:** Rather more amusingly, it also has the side effect of setting the major mode of Dired buffers to `shell-script-mode`, making it impossible to open any (as an error is thrown during the initialization).

Answer (score 0):

For me accepted answer give error:

> (error "Lisp nesting exceeds ‘max-lisp-eval-depth’")

Because it tried to apply the mode recursively, when it open a file it executed a mode and if the mode was changed it executed the eval again recursively:

For me this works:

```lisp
((nil (eval
       (lambda ()
         (when (and (string-match-p "\\.js\\'" buffer-file-name)
                    (not (string= (major-mode) "rjsx-mode")))
           (rjsx-mode))))))
```

For rjsx-mode that I wanted to apply for all js file in project directory.