# can I use .dir-locals.el to set a default mode for files, and still allow dired?

Tags: dired, debugging

I have a directory that is all little shell code snippets for being sourced.

Tried creating an auto-mode-alist, that does not seem to be effective, so tried creating a **.dir-locals.el** thusly:

```
((nil . ((mode . sh))))
```

which does indeed, set the mode of all files to sh-mode.

However, now cannot run dired, get this message:

dired-readin: Wrong type argument: stringp, nil

What should I do to allow dired to run normally in this dir?

Related: [How to set major mode for a file in .dir-locals.el?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/18054/how-to-set-major-mode-for-a-file-in-dir-locals-el)

Or, to rephrase the question, can specific files, not subdirs be specified, so as to only apply to those files?  IOW, not dot files?

### Addendum

This was the **auto-mode-alist** attempt:

```
(defvar home-lib
  `,(concat (substitute-in-file-name "$HOME/lib") "/.*\\'")
  "Regexp for auto-mode-alist to find anything in ~/lib to be a sh-mode file.")

(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist `(,home-lib . sh-mode))
```

Comment: Just what did you try? Show your code or give a recipe of commands used. And do you see the same problem if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)?

Comment: @Drew The code is in the question. What else do you expect the question to contain?

Comment: It would be interesting to see the attempt at setting auto-mode-alist, as it should be possible to set the mode for all files in this directory based on the path to the files, not just the file names.

Comment: @dithotx, your `auto-mode-alist` code works fine for me.  You haven't used `regexp-quote` on the literal portion of the pattern, so it's not the *correct* way to build that regexp; but most $HOME dir paths would probably not cause problems in practice.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding `.dir-locals.el`, assuming the files are being opened in `fundamental-mode`, you can simply target that:

```
((fundamental-mode . ((mode . sh))))
```

---

> Tried creating an `auto-mode-alist`, that does not seem to be effective

There's no reason why it shouldn't be effective.  e.g.:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist (cons REGEXP 'sh-mode))

Where REGEXP is a regular expression matching the filename.  e.g.:

- Any filename with a particular extension ".foo":
  (rx ".foo" eos)

- Any file in a specific directory:
  (rx bos "/path/to/directory/")

- Only *.c filenames under that directory:
  (rx bos "/path/to/directory/" (zero-or-more not-newline) ".c" eos)

- Match some sub-path anywhere in a filename:
  (rx "/sub/path/foo")

- A specific individual file:
  (rx bos "/path/to/file" eos)
```

Comment: Thanks, @phils.  First answer here was the ticket.

Comment: Thanks again @phils, both answers worked.  The problem with the **auto-mode-alist** may have had something to do with there being multiple instances, and the subsequent one was an accretion over several years.  Reworked it with the rx and regexp-opt and that fixed the issue, so the .dirs-local.el was no longer required.